# Retrieving robot orientation/location

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node/Tutorials/UsingTheHokuyoNode

Hi guys,

I am currently doing the tutorial above and I know this is quite stupid to ask but do you guys know how do I get to know my orientation of my robot(current just a sensor)?
What kind of ros command?

PS: using ROS fuerte

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90376/retrieving-robot-orientation/location/) by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2013-10-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-10-13**:
There is not simple command to get the orientation as that must be defined first. Orientation relative to what? Are you looking at pitch/roll angles only or do you care about orientation in some fixed world frame? In the latter case you need an algorithm like SLAM or localization.

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-13**:
I need to know the yaw pitch roll and the angle of the robot.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-10-13**:
Do you only have the laser as a sensor? Do you have a map that you localize in?

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-13**:
Yes I have a hokuyo laser as my sensor, as I am doing amcl I not yet have a map, just trying to figure out how can I display all those data in prompt or whatever to show it is functioning well.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-10-13**:
Without a map and other input, you need a SLAM approach like hector_mapping.

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-13**:
How am I suppose to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/hector_mapping

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0